# Can I disable a particular git command?

Tags: bash, git, tab-completion, bash-completion

With new versions of git new commands have been added which I will probably never use.
Is there a way I can disable these commands so that I my tab completion is faster?
For ex: before, `git check<tab>` would autocomplete to `git checkout`
But now `git check<tab>` doesn't tab complete due to there being `git check-mailmap` in the newer git version.

This is just one of the example.

Alternatively it would be great if I could "force" git to tab-complete "check" to `checkout` .

Edit: I use vanilla bash with no extra modifications

Comment: Do you use vanilla `bash` ? Do you have `zsh` or any completion plugin ?

Comment: What you actually need may be modifying the specified auto-complete file.

Comment: @Aserre I use vanilla ubuntu bash. I will add it to the question for clarification.

Comment: You should consider using the newer `git switch <branch>` instead of checkout for your navigation between branches. If you accidentally type `git checkout <filename>`, you undo all the changes to the file. It's `git switch -c <branch>` to create a new branch and switch to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The official way is to use the configuration `completion.commands` and remove the ones you don't want:

```
git config --global completion.commands -check-mailmap
```

However, you can do even more. There is a hack in `__git_main()` used for testing that you can abuse to do what you want:

```
GIT_TESTING_PORCELAIN_COMMAND_LIST="$(git --list-cmds=list-mainporcelain,alias)"
```

This will force Git's completion to show only the main commands (and aliases).

You need Git v2.18 or newer for these to work.

Comment: Wow, that's a heck of a lot cleaner than deleting stuff out of git-completion.bash.  I had no idea this existed.

Comment: Couldn't make it work on zsh… am I doomed? It's impossible to search about it, all results are generic auto-complete setup guides.

Comment: @gibatronic Zsh's completion is hopeless. You can use my own completion for Zsh which uses Git's official completion though: https://github.com/felipec/git-completion

Answer (score 3):

**To see how to remove items from the autocomplete, see FelipeC's answer.**

An alternative is to use git aliases to create shorter alternatives to the commands you commonly use.  For example:

`git config --global alias.co checkout`

Now you can type `git co` to check out files.

Comment: I didn't know we could set aliases! This is much better than what I wanted originally. Thank you!

Comment: The `_git_foo()`  functions only get called **after** the user has typed 'git foo <tab>`.

Comment: @FelipeC Feel free to post a better answer about how to remove commands from Git's autocomplete.  That would help everyone.

Comment: @RyanLundy I was typing exactly that.